# Laravel 5.2 error al subirlo en hosting

Tags: laravel

Tengo un proyecto hecho en laravel 5.2 con xampp en mi máquina local. Al momento de subirlo a un hosting, cuando intento entrar a la página, me devuelve un error   que dice que no encuentra el archivo (No such file or directory). Por lo que veo en el mensaje el problema está en que la página va a buscar el archivo a mi computadora local, y debería buscarlo en el servidor donde subí mi proyecto. La base de datos fue importada desde mi pc local a el servidor. He buscado pero no he encontrado ninguna solución. No entiendo por qué va a buscar el archivo a mi xampp local.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías empezar por borrar el caché de las sesiones y las vistas.

Comment: hola Shaz - Intente borrar la cache de las sesiones y las vistas pero aun sigue sin funcionar...

Answer (score 0):

¿Comprobaste que la carpeta **sessions** tenga permisos de escritura?

También puedes intentar con el comando `php artisan cache:clear` en tu máquina local y luego subir el proyecto a tu hosting.

Comment: Hola! intente con comando php cache clear pero no funciono...tmb le di permiso a la carpeta session y sigue sin funcioar...donde se define el archivo path? porque el problema es que la variable path esta apuntando a mi xampp local...

Comment: @RodrigoBanegas En ninguna parte se definen "paths" en Laravel, no es necesario.

Comment: Puede ser que la variable path quedo seteada en mi maquina local y cuando subi el proyecto a la web, fue subido con esa variable seteada? Lei por ahi, que puede ser problema de apache/xampp que setean todas las variables apuntando a el xampp local o algo asi...sabes algo de eso?

Comment: Saludos lograste resolver el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Estimado... 
Si no te funciono clear:cache podrias revisar los archivos que genera laravel para optimizar la carga de servicios de tu aplicación.

Te dejo los siguientes links...
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/59/clearing-the-compiled-class

https://sentinelstand.com/article/laravel-5-optimization-commands

En ambos links indican donde se encuentran los archivos. Revisalos.

Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Chequea los permisos de escritura de storage, y limpia las vistas con

```
php artisan view:clear
```